# Bootstrap 50% of .row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started using bootstrap and i have a problem with nesting heights in percentages. For example i have a .row with .col-sm-8 and .col-sm-4. There's bunch of content in .col-sm-8 and it determins the height of a column and it's parent .row. However, when I want to set 2 divs (.map and .contact) to 50% height each it leaves me with something like this.

[image]

Even if there is no content in both of those divs my .row height is much more then it used to be. How can i accomplish a layout that looks like the one in the next picture so that the heights of .row, .map and .cotact are completly dependent on the first columns height which is determined by the content in it.
I don't know what exactly would cause this problem. I hope you understood what I meant to say :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On your .row add the css:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display:         flex;
```

**update**: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xuoxz7zx/2/

Comment: I've never worked with flexbox. How do i make it work since the solution you posted doesn't quite get the job done. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

css

```
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1;
}

    .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        line-height: 0;
    }

    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="row clearfix">
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with jQuery.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  var correctHeight = ($('.col-sm-8').height) / 2;

  $('.map, .contact').height(correctHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap 4:

CSS :

```
#panel-1,
#panel-2 {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
}

#panel-1 {
  background: #CCFF00;
}

#panel-2 {
  background: #00FFCC;
  max-height: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
}

#panel-3 {
  background: #FFCC00;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div id="panel-1" class="row p-4">Scrollable content of Panel 1</div>
      <div id="panel-2" class="row p-4">Scrollable content of Panel 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="panel-3" class="col-8 p-4">Scrollable content of Panel 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[You can view demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/sw3tobmf/)